# Can I set UILabel to nil in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a table and want to set it to `nil` so that I can use an action on it to change its text, right now without nil it shows "optional" text!

```
@IBOutlet var nameLable: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



@IBAction func helloworldaction(nameTextField: UITextField) {
   nameLable.text = "\(nameTextField.text)"
}
```

but it shows errors when I change it to this:

`@IBOutlet var nameLable:  UILabel = nil`

what should I do??

Answer (score 1):

You don't want your label to be nil. You just want it's text to be empty.

```
@IBOutlet var nameLable: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // SET THIS
    nameLable.text = ""
}

@IBAction func helloworldaction(nameTextField: UITextField) {

    // And use nameTextField.text directly
    nameLable.text = nameTextField.text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is just `"\(nameTextField.text)"` - you're using string interpolation `"\(X)"` which is handy for printing the value without having to use a formatter, but is you're assigning a value - which is what you are doing here - you just use `nameTextField.text`

Then you can unwrap the option - as @Marina showed you - and you can also clear the label if the field is nil

```
if let text = nameTextField.text
{
    nameLable.text = text
}
else
{
    nameLable.text = ""
}
```

It's probably also worth putting some effort into spelling things correctly.  It's a lot easier to track problems down if you know that labels are all spelled the same way :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should unwrap an optional value nameTextField.text. It can look like:

```
if let text = nameTextField.text{
    nameLable.text = text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may do this:

```
nameLable.text = "\(nameTextField.text!)"
```

But forcing to unwrap is not a good option. You may create a variable to store the text value. Then in nameLable.text reference to the string instead straight from the label.